# Angular 2+: Mat Stepper stepcontrol binding doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

I have in my app a matStepper with its 2 first steps that look like this:

```
     <mat-step [stepControl]="actionFormGroup">...</mat-step>
     <mat-step [stepControl]="flightsFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="flightsFormGroup">
          <ng-template matStepLabel>Title</ng-template>
          <div class="central" fxLayoutGap="20px">
            <app-list-flights></app-list-flights>
            <div dir="rtl">
              <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="checkValidation()">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </mat-step>
<mat-step>...</mat-step>
```

In my typescript, the FormGroup declaration is like this:

```
export class NewReqComponent implements OnInit {

      actionFormGroup: FormGroup;
      flightsFormGroup: FormGroup;
      ngOnInit() {
        this.actionFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
          ctrl: ['', Validators.required]
        });
        this.flightsFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
          ctrl: [false, Validators.requiredTrue]
        });
      }
 }
```

My form control "ctrl" is modified by a few methods that set it true or false.
However, even when it's true, I cannot go to the next step. In the first step, where I only have one input, it works well, as soon as the field is filled I can go to the next step.

Does anyone know where the problem comes from?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the given details, you are missing the **matStepperNext** in the provided code.You can control the stepper to proceed further or not depending on valid status of the particular component through stepper index as mentioned above

With the given details , i am assuming this would resolve this issue,if not can you provide more details, git url if available.

```
<button mat-raised-button matStepperNext color="accent" (click)="checkValidation()">Next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it's not a direct answer to the question I think it might help others.

Here is an addition to the answer by [Ahmed Jahanzaib](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9424994/ahmed-jahanzaib)

In order to get access to MatHorizontalStepper in the component, you need to add `#stepper` identifier (you can set any name you like)

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper ... #stepper>
  ...
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

Then inside of your component class you need to inject the MatStepper

```
import { MatStepper } from '@angular/material';
...
export class NewReqComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('stepper', { static: false }) stepper: MatStepper;
```

- The first argument `'stepper'` should be the same as the identifier `#stepper` in the HTML file.
- The second argument `{static: false|true}` is required for Angular 8 only.
- Now you can get access to it using `this.stepper`

Answer (score -1):

You need to wrap your Mat Stepper html like this:

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [selectedIndex]="selectedIndexVal" (selectionChange)="doSomething($event)">
<mat-step [stepControl]="actionFormGroup">...</mat-step>
     <mat-step [stepControl]="flightsFormGroup">
        <form [formGroup]="flightsFormGroup">
          <ng-template matStepLabel>Title</ng-template>
          <div class="central" fxLayoutGap="20px">
            <app-list-flights></app-list-flights>
            <div dir="rtl">
              <button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="checkValidation()">Next</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </mat-step>
<mat-step>...</mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

In your component class, make `doSomething()` like this:

```
public doSomething(event: StepperSelectionEvent) {
   this.stepper.selectedIndex= index;
}
```

Base on true and false, change the `this.stepper.selectedIndex` value respetively.

Comment: how you declared "stepper" in ts file can u please tell me